# What is it called when a variable is assigned to the return value of a function?

Tags: python, variables, initialization

I've learned what an assignment expression is, but I'm having trouble expressing the difference between these two types of variables:

- The first type is a variable that is assigned an expression
- The second is a variable that is assigned a return value of a function

From my understanding, it would still be called a variable initialization. However, I wouldn't know the most concise way to communicate the difference between the two.

If this is a variable initialization:

```py
my_var = 7
```

...then is `number` a variable initialization also?:

```py
def return_number():
    return 7

number = return_number()
```

Is there an easy way to communicate the difference between them?

Comment: yes both are the variable initialization.

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between `my_var` and `number`.  Both have the same type (`int`) and the same value (`7`).

Comment: Is there really not a term to express that the way in which they were created was different?

Comment: I guess there doesn't have to be... but this has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: I've never heard a term for it.  There just isn't must of a distinction between the two to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Okay well thank you for your comments. I'm still a bit surprised but it will subside

Comment: The way that the variable itself was created is the same in both cases (an assignment).  The right-hand part of the assignment is different -- one is a literal, the other is a function call.  But that doesn't translate into any difference in the resulting variables.